# Join two arrays of different size with condition

Tags: python, numpy

i have two arrays of different sizes and i want them to joint in one only if first three elements match.

for exapmle:

```
A1 = [
    [1,8,9,8,2],
    [2,9,9,8,2],
    [1,7,7,8,2],
    [8,6,2,6,7]
]


A2 = [[2,9,9,30,60],
      [8,6,2,70,20]]

Result = [[2,9,9,8,2,30,60]
         [8,6,2,6,7,70,20]]
```

I guess there is some numpy function for this but i couldn't find it.

Comment: I doubt there is a preexisting function (numpy or otherwise) to do this, but as Aziz shows below, this can done in a fairly straightforward manner with a list comprehension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
result = [i+j[3:] for i in A1 for j in A2 if i[:3]==j[:3]]
```

This is equivalent to:

```
result = []
for i in A1:
    for j in A2:
       if (i[:3] == j[:3]): # if the first three element match

           # skip the first 3 elements in j (they're already included in i)
           result.append(i + j[3:])
```

**To do this with `numpy` arrays**:

```
result = np.array([np.concatenate((i,j[3:])) for i in A1 for j in A2 if all(i[:3]==j[:3])])
```

Here we used `np.concatenate()` to merge the two arrays, and used `all()` to compare the first 3 elements.

Comment: Hi, thanks for great answer. its only work with list and wanted to apply it on numpy array. But i guess i have to convert to list

Comment: @relnet I've updated the answer with code for `numpy` arrays.

Answer (score 0):

A general-purpose way to do this (e.g. if you might have arbitrary numbers of these lists) might be to use `itertools.groupby`:

```
result = []
for p, g in itertools.groupby(sorted(A1+A2), lambda arr: arr[:3]):
     group = list(g)
     if len(group) >= 2:
         result.append(p + [i for arr in group for i in arr[3:]])
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is run a test on the first 3 elements of each array and then use the spread operator to join them:

```
if A1[:3] == A2[:3]:
    result = [*A1, *A2]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a broadcasted comparison, no loops are needed.

```
match = (A1[:,None,:])[:,:,:3] == A2[:,:3]
R1, R2 = np.where(match.sum(axis=2)==3)
result = np.hstack((A1[R1],A2[R2,-2:]))
```

`A1[:,None,:]` returns a view of shape (4,1,5) as opposed to (4,5); this allows you to do a broadcasted operation between A1 and A2, giving you the bool array `match` of shape (4,2,3). Taking the sum across the third axis basically tells you which row in A1 is matching with which row of A2, from which it's simple to create te result.